# how do I describe magic in a fictional story?

Tags: fiction, characters, fantasy, description, book

In my writing I need to describe a character being enchanted by a spell and pulled towards a house.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to our site! Your question is attracting downvotes (and might end up being closed) because you give very little detail to explain what you're finding difficult about describing the use of magic. Have you read books where magic is used (e.g. *Harry Potter* series)? To avoid DVs and/or closure, please [edit] your question to give more detail on the research you've already done and what specifically is the difficulty you're having. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Decide how the spell does it.

Then decide how the point of view character would experience it.

Then describe that.

Is it like a wall moving behind her, pushing her toward it?  Is it like a rope pulling on her?  Is it like the ground under her feet is moving?